# Why aren't my links taking me into my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web, controller

I guess I don't completely understand how urls work with C# projects, in the sense that I don't know how to specify a url to go through the controller and not just return a aspx page.

Say I am trying to get to my project's Index page through a Controller named "ScholarshipController.cs". I would think to hit the Index method/action in this controller, my url would be as follows (my app's name is "TuitionAssistance" fyi):

```
http://localhost/TuitionAssistance/Scholarship/Index
```

However, running this url just returns the aspx page named "Index.aspx" located in the "Scholarship" view file without hitting the Controller. Why is this happening, and how do I get it to go through the controller so the Index page, when loaded, will have the appropriate information loaded onto it?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Route.config:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ScholarshipTuitionAssistance
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            /* Scholarship */

            /* Scholarship */
            //routes.MapRoute("TuitionAssistance",
            //    "tuition/{name}",
            //    new { controller = "TuitionAssistance", action = "Index", name = "" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TuitionAssistance",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{employee_number}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "TuitionAssistance", employee_number = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Scholarship",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{employee_number}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Scholarship", employee_number = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Details",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Scholarship", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us RouteConfig class. It should be inside App_Start folder.

Comment: Just added it to my post. Thanks

Comment: I'm hesitant to touch anything in this because everything seems to be working in production. It's just when I try to run things locally that it spits in my face...

Comment: All 3 routes are identical in that they accept between 0 and 3 segments. The 2nd and 3rd route definitions are pointless since they will never be executed (any url that would match them would also match the 1st route). And none of the routes you have shown would ever match the url you have shown.

Comment: Thank you! I've never worked with routes before, so this is the kind of info I was hoping for!

Answer (score 3):

Your route (URL) cannot match anything that actually exists on the filesystem. In your example here, you apparently have a file, `[document root]\Scholarship\Index.aspx`. As a result, a request for `Scholarship/Index` will return that file, instead of invoking the ASP.NET MVC machinery to load a controller action.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue though. Because, the actual location of the Index.aspx is [document root]\Views\Scholarship\Index.aspx   does that change anything? Or do you still think that would be a problem?

Doesn't the "action name" need to be the same as the "view/page name" to return the appropriate view? Would I need to change the controller name or something?

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that's an interesting scenario, too. So there, MVC is being invoked, but because of the way it supports using Web Forms within an MVC site, it will load the view directly rather than trying to render an action. The presence of an aspx file basically short circuits the rest of the request processing. Regardless, the same solution applies, your route needs to be distinct from any physical aspx file.

Comment: Sorry, but that confuses me. I thought actions are supposed to be named the same as the aspx file, and the controller is supposed to have the same name as the view folder that file is located in?

How would I go about creating a distinct path to the view file without screwing this up?

Comment: The action should be named the same as the *cshtml*. Aspx files are self-contained and don't utilize things like controllers and actions.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC ASP.NET, think of those types of links as a way to call your methods in your controller.  When that link is accessed, your controller does a bunch of junk and then returns an ActionResult (or other things).  This ActionResult, for the sake of this explanation, is the markup that is written in the corresponding view file.  Controller - >index() will return the view called index under views - > controller.  If you want to pass information to your view, you will pass a model that has all of your information in it to the view from your index controller (return View(MyFancyModel)).  The view will have a razor line at the top such as: @model The.Namespace.Wherever.my.model.is

The scaffolded controllers and views in Visual Studio for the index page specifically, only pass a list of the items in the corresponding database.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I've never seen someone put it so clearly before. I've had to make assumptions about these things in the past. I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  Honestly, I'm kind of worried I misunderstood your question after I posted my answer.  Is that what you were wondering about or did I totally miss the nail?

Comment: Haha I mean you got half of my problem. I was hoping to get a clear definitive answer of how urls work with controllers in C# (which you gave me). However, I still need to figure out why I'm not hitting my controller in this particular situation. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: One thing I like to do in those instances is: import the System.Windows.Forms .dll and then call MessageBox.Show("I made it here") in my controller method.  This will give you a surefire way to tell if you're problem is in the controller method return line or if it's in the way you're trying to get to the controller

Comment: Would just adding a breakpoint in the controller in debug mode accomplish the same thing? or is there something special about using a message box?

Comment: Yes, that would accomplish the same thing.  It's just more visual for me personally.